# Save Text Box Template

Tags: arcmap, text

Is there a way to save a text box's formatting and text so that you can insert it into a map with only a couple of clicks? For example, I have to insert a box that reads "CONFIDENTIAL NOT FOR PUBLIC RELEASE" on lots of maps, and it would save some time and annoyance if I didn't have to go through the process of changing borders, backgrounds, text size and alignment, and all that jazz every time.

Comment: I would expect that you could write a Python AddIn using ArcPy that would do this.

Comment: Save it in a separate mxd. All you'll need to do after is copy paste to a new one.